# Java: SelectionKey.interestOps(int) not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, selector, nio

In my application I use multiple threads to handle client connections.

i found a very weird behavior when debugging - I have a SelectionKey that by invoking (using the debugger) its interestOps() method the return value is 1 (READ), but when I send data to the socket corresponding to that key the selector not wakes up..

If using the debugger I changes the specific selection key interest ops to 1 (even though it was 1) the selector suddenly react to that change.

I have only one thread handling a connection at a given time but this thread is not specific to that connection, if I disable the multi-threading (set the thread pool to be of size 1) this problem never occurred.

By looking at the SelectionKey class documentation - this method should be thread safe - did i miss something?

Comment: Did you actually step into the source code? The javadocs don't always mention whether or not a method is thread-safe.

Comment: @user1329572 Yes, the method does 2 significant things - changes its own interested ops field and then call the channel's translateAndSetInterestOps method - this is where I think that the problem occurred but as I said - I have only one thread handling a connection at a time, I also synchronize on the key upon changes its interestOp but that not fix the bug..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved after i moved all the changes to the interestOps to be done on the selector thread - so I guess that interestOps(int) is not thread safe.

**Edit**
by moving all the interestOps changes to the selector thread I also gain 30% speedup - not sure why but this is the only change between my tests..

Answer (score 3):

It's not a question of thread safety. If there is a `select()` currently in progress, it has already read all the interestOps out of all the registered keys and is selecting on those values as they were when read: the values are passed to the operating system and an operating system blocking operation is in progress. Changing the `interestOps` in the middle of a select operation can't affect that select operation, only the next one(s).

Comment: i was "waking up" the selector after each key change - that didnt help.. i even use the select(int) method with timeout of 10 seconds just to see if this behavior can be "fixed" using the selector - and it was not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late to the party, but for people who will, like me, visit in the future:

"Selection keys are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. The operations of reading and writing the interest set will, in general, be synchronized with certain operations of the selector."

Taken from ["SelectionKey in Java 7"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html)

Comment: It is important to understand that they can block while the selector is selecting - which may cause a deadlock. So while they technically thread safe in the "correctness" side of the term they are less safe in the "progress" side of the term

Comment: Yes, I learned it the hard way. Generally it seems that even thought this solution was created with speed and efficiency in mind, it fell short of the expectations. In case of connecting to other hosts (so when creating channel, registering it with selector and setting interest ops), it is required to create additional lock, and do something like this: selKey.interestOps(OP_WRITE); lock.lock(); selector.wakeUp(); while connecting, and then doing the following: selector.select(); synchronized (lock) { } ; in selector loop - otherwise selector could wake and go to sleep.

Comment: you can actually use a much better solution than using locks: just  create a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> selectorOps` field and have the selector thread run over that queue immediately after each select  and run all the runnables in that queue. Then, all you have to do if you want to change some key's interested ops is to call: `selectorOps.add(() -> key.interestedOps(ops)); selector.wakeup();` - no lock is needed.

Comment: @bennyl I tried this solution earlier and it failed miserably for some corner case, but honestly I can't remember what it was - maybe I'll try that again and check if it works. It would be great if it worked, since solution with additional lock is, let's face it, abysmal.

Comment: @bennyl Ok, I remember now. From time to time change to ops wasn't immediately recognized as there was race condition: new op was added to the queue, but selector's thread has already finished reading from the queue, and then wakeUp() on it was called, but it was lost since selector hasn't yet entered state where wakeUp() would work. Result - new op present in queue and select() sleeping. This wasn't bad when there was a lot of network activity, but in case of many connections and low network activity (for example small message every minut or so) this was happening quite often.

Comment: @JędrzejDudkiewicz According to the `Selector` docs, and my own experiences, there shouldn't be a race condition if you finished adding the new op to the queue before calling `wakeup()`.  `wakeup()` either wakes an in-progress `select()`, or it causes the next `select()` to return immediately.  If the selecting thread had passed the queue already but hadn't yet slept then `wakeup()` will make it skip the `select()` and loop back around and hit the queue again.

Comment: @billie ok, i understand. It is possible that I had a bug in my code, but it is highly improbable as it was pretty simple. I'll check it again. Thanks for an insight.

Comment: It WAS a bug and pretty stupid one at that, so this solution should work like a charm. Thanks for info once again!

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for the late comment, but I think it's better to clarify)
As the javadoc said (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html):

> Exactly how this synchronization is performed is implementation-dependent: In a naive implementation, reading or writing the interest set may block indefinitely if a selection operation is already in progress; in a high-performance implementation, reading or writing the interest set may block briefly, if at all. In any case, a selection operation will always use the interest-set value that was current at the moment that the operation began.

So to fully understand the original question, we'll need to know in which enviroment (OS, kernel version, jdk version) it is happening.

(Sorry I should send it as inline comment, but I'm not allowed to)

---

Reedit:

According to more modern jdk's doc (java 11+), SelectionKey should be thread safe: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html

More specifially, `SelectionKey#interestOps​(int ops)` is supposed to

> may be invoked at any time. If this method is invoked while a selection operation is in progress then it has no effect upon that operation; the change to the key's interest set will be seen by the next selection operation.

Comment: I think you should update your answer to take account of the spec changes in Java SE 11. In particular, SelectionKey, including the interestOps method, were re-specified to be thread safe.